# Index of a array in C# windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to get only the odd or only the even index of a array list.
For example, my array list is 20.
And i want to separate out the odd and the even index.

Odd: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
Even: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20

How can i go about doing it??

Comment: want to separate it.. such tat for my quiz i can define it as the odd one will be the answer and even one will be a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wouldn't it make more sense to make a structure like

```
class QuizItem 
{ 
    public string Question { get; set; } 
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

and make an array of those instead of misusing array indices?

Comment: because for my quiz there is four option only one of the option will be the correct answer..

Comment: @ben tan: If you have 4 answers all you have to do is to switch from a single string to an array of strings:
`public string[] Answer { get; set; }`
This is really the best way to do it, everything else is misusing array indices as John Gardner said.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Phone 7 I'd do it like this

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 21).ToList();

var even = values.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                 .Where(elt => elt.index % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(elt => elt.value);

var odd = values.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .Where(elt => elt.index % 2 != 0)
                .Select(elt => elt.value);
```

I'd be inclined to use similar code on any other .NET platform too ...

Comment: He is referring to odd or even indexes, not values in the collection/array.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension to "optimize things". Something like the following should work:

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int startIndex) {
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

        int count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items) {
            if (startIndex > 0) {
                startIndex--;
                continue;
            }
            else if (count % 2 != 0)
                continue;

            count++;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
var even = values.EveryOther(0);
var odd= values.EveryOther(1);
```